# How to get Windows product key for an out-of-support notebook with a failed hard drive?

Tags: windows-10, laptop

I've bought Lenovo IdeaPad 110-17ACL notebook, with Windows 10 Home Edition (Russian). The notebook's support period is finished. Its hard drive failed completely, Linux live USB doesn't even recognize it as a hard drive. I replaced the hard drive with an SSD, and now I am trying to reinstall Windows 10 Home Edition (Russian) from a pendrive. It asks for the product key, but I can't find it anywhere on notebook's case.

[image: notebook bottom label]

Comment: The Win-10 Key is actually stored in BIOS. In the past I have used a (unfortunately Windows only) utility called RWEverything to read the Windows key. These days Firefox warns me that the site that hosts that serves malware. So if you are feeling brave and can boot Windows long enough to run RWeverything you should be able to find what you seek.

Comment: You don't need a product key, install W10 and it will activate using the embedded bios key

Comment: What your asking to do, isn’t necessary, if your having a problem activating Windows 10 it means you are attempting to install an edition other than cane with the device.  Just skip the step asking for the product key, once Windows is installed, Windows 10 will automatically be activated

Comment: Thank you guys for all the answers. I've found out that install screen actually has a label "skip this". It is written with tiny white font on blue background, I couldn't notice it. Now Windows is installed, got it's product key from BIOS/UEFI and refuses to activate over internet. I am gonna bring that up to Microsoft support.

Comment: How do you know it got its product key from BIOS? How did you create the install disc? You should confirm your laptop has a BIOS key with produkey or another key recovery tool. Then confirm Windows is using that key. You should be creating the installation media with the “media creation tool” and making sure to choose the same version and language of Windows (home / pro) as what the laptop came with during install. Windows 10 typically pulls the key automatically during install and doesn’t even ask what version to install nor does it ask for a key. So it must not actually recognize the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command prompt, type "wmic path softwarelicensingservice get /all /format:list | findstr OA3" Even non-activated, command prompt should work.
You probably already know if it actually came with Win10, or was Win8. If it was 8, and not actually upgraded, you're going to have to go the install 8, upgrade it to 8.1, then 10. If there's a cheat for it, haven't found it...yet.

Have bought from folks that had no idea which version they had, and if it was touchscreen, they might have liked it with Metro and reverted.